# Date string from GregorianCalendar based on locale

Tags: java, android, date, gregorian-calendar

I am creating an Android application. I have a GregorianCalendar variable. I want to get the date from this variable as MM-dd-yyyy if the locale is US or dd-MM-yyyy if the locale is EU and so on. I don't want to hard code each locale string, I want to make it depend on the phone's locale.

The problem is that after looking through tens of similar questions, I still couldn't get this to work. I am guessing it's two or three lines of code, perhaps using SimpleDateFormat or GregorianCalendar.get() or getDisplayName().

Thanks for the help.

Comment: just to know, which country are you targetting with locale EU?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, it was supposed to be RU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
    GregorianCalendar gc = ...
    String str = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(gc.getTime());
```

BTW default date format (SHORT) for US is `dd/MM/yy` eg 30/05/13

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, yourLocale);
String formattedDate = df.format(yourcalender.getTime());
```

with yourcalender is GregorianCalendar variable

Comment: Works just fine. I picked the other one as the answer because not specifying the locale means it automatically uses the system default, as I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Better yet why not use the user's own preferred date format? `Locale.getLocale()` returns the user's preferred locale, you can use this to format all your localised values (dates, times, currency etc) and know that you're giving the user a format that they chose.